# Why the transpose of $A$ is not looking at the transformation $A$ in the dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, dual-spaces

Most of the time people are saying that in order to have a better understanding about what the transpose really represents is this:

> We have a linear transformation $T : V \to V$ with $V$ a finite vector space.  Then the tranpose is a linear application in the dual space, namely, $T^* : V^* \to V^*$ such that $T^*(\phi)(v) = \phi(Tv)$.

I understand what all of this means, but what is the motivation behind this definition of the transpose?

For me, if we have a linear map $T : V \to V$, then a more natural thing to look at is this:  what is the transformation $T$ in the dual space $V^*$ ?
 In this case this is simply the linear application $T^* : V^* \to V^*$ such that : $T^*(\langle y, . \rangle) = \langle Ty, . \rangle$. For me this is a natural transformation to look at, namely, the application $T$ acting on the dual space.

Yet I don't understand the motivation behind the transpose. Why this definition, and not another?

Thank you!

Comment: I have never , ever heard that "definition" of the transpose... Perhaps there is some mistranslation here.

Comment: The first definition is independent of the choice if the inner product. The second should give different definitions for different inner products.

Comment: @Dog_69 These two definitions aren't the same ! The second one is the more natural one to me : Namely what is $T$ in the dual space, but I don't understand the motivation behind the definition of the tranpose (that is the one in the yellow box)

Comment: @DonAntonio This is the common definition of the transpose, with this in mind we  have $\langle Ax, y \rangle = \langle x, ^t Ay \rangle$.

Comment: Yes, they look different. They may agree if you define $T^(\langle y,\cdot\rangle) =\langle y,T\cdot\rangle$, but still... At the end, the transpose is the pullback of a 1-form.

Comment: @Dog_69 Yes i this case they agree... But this is not natural at all for me to defined $T^*(<y, .>) = <y, T.>$ and not as : $T^*(<y, .>) = <Ty,.>$ right ?

Comment: The definition in the yellow box can be written as: $\;T^*: \phi \longmapsto \phi\circ T$. It is the most natural because it is independent of the choice of any basis, and it doesn't require inner product spaces. Actually, it is valid for    `modules over a ring`.

Comment: @Bernard This is indeed a nice point of view. Nevertheless even if this definition is independent from the choice of basis, it doesn't really represent something when defined this way (at least from my poor point of view) whereas what I had in mind was really clear : the action $T$ in the dual space

Comment: This definition shows $T$ has  a right action in the dual space.  Also it is adapted to the categorical point of view

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your answer. unfortunately I don't know all of this. So I guess I need to get deeper in these topics to maybe understand that this definition makes a lot of sens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transpose map $T^*\colon W^*\to V^*$ can be defined for every linear map $T\colon V\to W$, where the vector spaces need not be endowed with an inner product and could be infinite dimensional as well.

The case of $T\colon V\to V$ where $V$ is a finite dimensional inner product space (over the reals, for simplicity) is a bit different, but not really too much.

The inner product allows you to define an isomorphism $\Phi\colon V\to V^*$, via the mapping $v\mapsto\Phi(v)=\hat{v}$, where $\hat{v}(w)=\langle v,w\rangle$.

This mapping is linear and injective, because $\langle v,w\rangle=0$ for all $w$ implies $v=0$. Hence, due to $V$ being finite dimensional, $\Phi$ is an isomorphism.

Now consider the map $T'\colon V\to V$ defined by
$$
T'=\Phi^{-1}\circ T^*\circ\Phi
$$
where $T^*\colon V^*\to V^*$ is defined by $T^*(\varphi)=\varphi\circ T$.

Consider now $v\in V$; then $\Phi\circ T'(v)=\Phi(T'(v))=\widehat{T'(v)}$ is the map such that
$$
\widehat{T'(v)}(w)=\langle T'(v),w\rangle
$$
by definition. On the other hand, $T^*\circ\Phi(v)=T^*(\hat{v})=\hat{v}\circ T$ is the map such that
$$
\hat{v}\circ T(w)=\hat{v}(T(w))=\langle v,T(w)\rangle
$$
Thus $T'$ is *exactly* the unique linear map $T'\colon V\to V$ such that, for all $v,w\in V$,
$$
\langle T'(v),w\rangle=\langle v,T(w)\rangle
$$
and the argument above is precisely the proof that this $T'$ exists.

---

What if $T\colon V\to W$ and both spaces are finite dimensional? To every basis $\mathscr{B}$ of a vector space, there corresponds a unique *dual basis* in the dual space, $\mathscr{B}^*$. If $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis of $V$ and $\mathscr{D}$ is a basis of $W$, we can compute the matrix $A$ of $T$ with respect to these basis. Then the matrix of $T^*\colon W^*\to V^*$ with respect to the dual bases is precisely the transpose matrix of $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In your last paragraph it means that :  if $T: W \to V$ is the linear application sending the basis $B$ of $W$ to the basis $D$ of $V$ then it's tranpose is the linear application in the dual space sending $B^*$ to $D^*$ ?

Comment: @dghkgfzyukz A linear map doesn't send bases to bases, generally. I was talking about the matrix of $T\colon V\to W$ *with respect to the bases* $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{D}$.

Comment: Yes sorry. I meant the following :  let $\mathscr{B} = (e_1, ..., e_n)$ be a basis of $V$ and  $T : V \to V$ be the linear map and let $k :  V \to V^*$ be the linear map sending the basis $\mathscr{B}$ to the basis $\mathscr{B}^*$  then we can defined the tranpose $T^* : V^* \to V^*$ of $T$ as : $T^*(v) = k(T(k^{-1}(v)))$ ?

Comment: @dghkgfzyukz Yes, but that's the wrong way to do it, because the transpose can be defined *independently* of bases.

Comment: Great! Yes you are right about the basis. Now it seems natural for me to have such a definition. I am going to re-read your answer in order to better grasp all of this. Thank you for your patience.